# New Document Library look doesn't use my masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage

Microsoft's new look for Document Libraries doesn't seem to use my custom master page. This article (http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2016/06/adopting-the-modern-sharepoint-online-document-libraries/) says custom master pages aren't supported at the moment. That implies it may come later.

Has anyone else had to address this yet? The primary need of the custom master page is load some external javascript files. Changing the "SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience" from new to classic seems to be the best temporary fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've outlined this pretty heavily, what is supported and what isn't [here](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Differences-between-the-new-document-library-experience-and-classic-mode-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). I know there is a [uservoice topic](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th) on this that they are considering. As this is something new, expect it to evolve. Their guidance is if you need to utilize a feature listed on that article, use the classic experience.

There are other ways to load external JavaScript without having to customize the master page, look into [User Custom Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538686%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). We use PowerShell to staple things like Google Analytics to sites to track views as User Custom Actions, or jQuery.

This however, is still only applicable to the Classic View experience. If you set your tenant to use classic mode, you can use this injection technique to staple your customizations without the needs to modify your master page, which is the preferred method per the PnP group as per last year's Ignite conference.

And the dev group just released a blog post with more information, http://dev.office.com/blogs/update-on-modern-document-libraries-and-extensiblity.

Comment: The blog post you linked indicated that only URL-based Custom Actions are supported. How are you able to inject custom JavaScript with them?

Comment: @RobWindsor It implies so, and has to be the case. We see Nintex Forms in the ribbon of our modern lists.

Comment: Sorry I think we're taking about Custom Actions in two different contexts. I wasn't asking about the ability to get buttons on the command bar, I was asking about the ability to inject JavaScript into the page.  You stated in your answer that you were able to get JavaScript into the page using UserCustomActions. I was wondering how you did it. I've tried to add script using Web scoped UserCustomActions and while things work as expected with pages in Classic Mode they don't work with Modern pages.

Comment: That still isn't possible afaik, the instances where we result to stapling UCAs at the web level are reverted back to the classic experience, I'll update it to be more clear in what I was trying to convey.

Comment: Trying to do something similar to you @Rob, and afaik there's no way of doing that currently. First answer in the faqs at https://blogs.office.com/2016/06/07/modern-document-libraries-in-sharepoint/ states that you'll need to use classic mode to use these 'unsupported features'.